# Can I make a THREE.js shape from a series of contours?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Let's say I have three flat shapes. For simplicity we'll make them circles:

[image: Three circles]

Is there any way in THREE.js to 'stack' these vertically and create a shape that fills in the space between them? If you imagine those circles stacked vertically, the eventual shape I'd want would be a sort of flat-topped cone.

Comment: Is the side profile linear between shapes, or is it a step function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process is called extrusion and is showed here - http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Extrusion.html

I've never tried it myself, so I can't help with actual use.